# Javascript - Display value of object from the third keys in a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object like:

```
{
  id: 50
  code: 112
  applicant: "individual", 
  application_id: 53, 
  appref: "ZAK00053", 
  date: "2019-01-11", 
}
```

To access the data, I use `for..in` loop

```
for(let keys in data){
  console.log(data[keys])
}
```

In the loop, how do I want to display the values that start from key `applicant` and onwards?

The values will only be `individual, 53, ZAK00053, 2019-01-11`

Do I have to convert the `object` to `array`?

Comment: Is it, that you want to ignore `id` and `code`? Then, just don't print these. The order of the declaration logically doesn't matter (although, technically, the order is preserved)

Comment: the data is from database query. I need the id & code but not for display. The values that I need is to display it in a table. The id & code is for me to insert in on a link

Comment: So then: Ignore these two properties

Comment: ignore means not to insert it in the object? But I need the Id and code on the same page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To approach what you actually want to achieve, I would ignore the two properties `id` and `code` rather than trying to rely on the order.

```
for(let key in data){
  if (key == "code" || key == "id")
      continue;
  console.log(data[key]);
  // ... do other stuff here, if needed
}
```

This way, you don't need to rely on the order of the properties at all.

```
for(let key in data){
  if (key != "code" && key != "id"){
      console.log(data[key]);
      // ... do other stuff here, if needed
  }
}
```

This would do the trick as well, if you want to avoid the `continue` statement.

Answer (score 2):

Object properties only have a well-defined order in ES6+ (insertion order), but if you can trust that you're in an ES6 environment and the object is defined as you describe, you can find the index of `applicant` in the object's `Object.keys`, and then use `.slice`:

```js
const obj = {
  id: 50,
  code: 112,
  applicant: "individual", 
  application_id: 53, 
  appref: "ZAK00053", 
  date: "2019-01-11", 
};
const index = Object.keys(obj).indexOf('applicant');
const values = Object.values(obj).slice(index);
console.log(values);
```

It's a strange thing to try to do, though - better to make an explicit blacklist or whitelist of keys to exclude or include, if that's a possibility.

Comment: Given the fact that he is using the `let` keyword lets me assume that the code would not run in a non-ES6 env ;-)

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. A reasonable build process will transpile ES6+ syntax (in development source) to ES5 for production. Seeing ES6+ syntax in development code which will eventually be implemented in ES5 clients is pretty common.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the data object by selecting `id`, `code`, and use the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to grab everything else, then just iterate over those properties.

```js
const data = {
  id: 50,
  code: 112,
  applicant: "individual", 
  application_id: 53, 
  appref: "ZAK00053", 
  date: "2019-01-11", 
};

const { id, code, ...rest } = data;

for (let keys in rest) {
  console.log(data[keys]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may add some control on for loop:

```
let i = 0;

for(let keys in data){
    if(i>1)
     console.log(data[keys]);
    i++;
}
```

Hoping it help you!

Comment: This, again, only is guaranteed to work in an ES6+ environment as the order of the properties is not well-defined (by definition) in ES5. I am aware that it would work in most engines anyway.